# Are Android Kotlin modules the same as Java packages?

Tags: android, kotlin

The definition of the "internal"-keyword in Kotlin says: "Internal: Visible inside the same module".

**What is meant with "module"?**

I know the concept of packages from Java. Is that meant? Or are Kotlin-"modules" something different?

Comment: They refer to compilation modules, while packages refer to directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [A module is a set of Kotlin sources compiled together:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html?_ga=2.239092867.1207972422.1592127411-2111111758.1574786618#modules)
>
> - an IntelliJ IDEA module;
> - a Maven project;
> - a Gradle source set (with the exception that the test source set can access the internal declarations of main);
> - a set of files compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.

The equivalent of Java packages in Kotlin is... well, [packages](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html).